Showing $\forall m\in\mathbb{N}:3\nmid m\land 1\leq m\leq 3^n\implies \exists k\in\mathbb{N}:2^k\equiv m \pmod {3^n}$
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be given -- here $\mathbb{N}$ does not contain $0$. It is fairly straightforward to show that $2^k$ is always congruent to some integer $m$ modulo $3^n$ such that $3$ does not divide $m$. One can write down couple of cases for $k,n$ to see that the converse also seems to be true, i.e. that for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $1\leq m\leq 3^n$ and $3\nmid m$, there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $2^k$ is congruent to $m$ modulo $3^n$. How could I prove this? I am quite rusty with my number theory and modular arithmetic.
I do recall that Euler's theorem, which states that if $a,b$ are coprime integers, then the multiplicative inverse of $a$ modulo $b$ is $a^{\phi(b)-1}$ where $\phi$ is the Euler's totient function. I just do not see how this could be used in our case. Thanks in advance!

"Let $k,n$ be given..." That is a strange start, because you need to show $k$ exists.'

It seems like you want to show that $2$ is a generator modulo $3^n$ for any $n.$ The notation obscures that fact.
